# Run overlay from bottom to top, rather than top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give the effect of a percentage over a building. So i have an overlay going in front of an image to give some sort of effect of raising. It's working but going top to bottom rather than bottom to top. How do i reference the ofset to be right?

Heres what it looks like at the moment

[image]

Heres my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  overlay = $("#overlay");
img = $("#myimg");
img.load( function(){
  var myPercent = 30;
  overlay.width($("#myimg").width());
  var myHeight = $("#myimg").height() / 100 * myPercent;
  alert(myHeight);
  overlay.height(myHeight);
  overlay.css("top", img.offset().top + "px");
  overlay.css("left", img.offset().left + "px");
});
});

</script>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
<img id="myimg" src="building.png" />
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/7vA9U/ jsfiddle

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with your issue..

Comment: Have you tried some like this: `overlay.css("top", ((img.offset().top + img.height() - myHeight)) + "px");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the overlay the following CSS:

```
#text-ovrelay {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This way, it's docked to bottom, and not to top.

**EDIT:** Took your code and changed it a little bit. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/7vA9U/1/).

Comment: Thanks for that, i've now posted it on jsfiddle above, i'm already doing most of that in the css apart from top was 0 not auto, but it didn't seem to make a difference